# Which modeling tools and modifiers use global space and which use local space?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

When modeling and using modifiers some tools and modifiers use global space for their operations e.g. extrude, move and the boolean modifier, while others use local space e.g. insert, bevel and the bevel modifier.
Sometimes the choice is pretty obvious e.g. move or scale, but othertimes it seems kind of arbitrary like with the bevel operation.

Is it somewhere documented which operations use which coordinate space?

Comment: In short, edit mode operations (such as pretty much all of the modifiers) use the local transforms while object mode operations use the global matrix, or any other matrix that's currently selected in the viewport (local,normal, gimbal, view, or even custom ones)